# Storing run time logs in a folder

Tags: linux, shell, command

I am running a shell script in Linux environment to create some logs (dynamic log files) as text files.

I want to store all the log files created into a single folder after some particular time.

So how can I do that? Can anyone suggest some commands?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the script you can define that directory as a variable and you can use that one across the script.

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_DIR=/tmp/logs
LOG_FILE=$LOG_DIR/log_file.$$ ## $$ will create the different log file for each and every run
                              ## You can also do it by using some time stamp using date command.

<Your commands>  >> $LOG_FILE
```

Comment: Hi Shriharsha, I am executing some server stat collection commands in Linux severs and the logs file content are getting updated for a particular time span. So after the particular time span I want to store all the created files in 1 folder so that it will b easy for me to collect. One more thing the folder should be created after the                   completion  of  execution of the shell script.

Comment: Hi Shriharsha, I am able to create a folder(with permissions) in which   I will store the runtime logs. I am using LOG_DIRECTORY1=$(mkdir -m 777 DEMO_${HOST}_${NOW1}_50users) command to create the directory with permission. After that I am creating the log by vmstat -n 10 400 > VMStat_DEMO_${HOST}_${NOW}.txt & command. After that for moving the created file to created directory I am using mv -t $LOG_DIRECTORY1 VMStat_DEMO_${HOST}_${NOW}.txt command. But it is not working. HOST and NOW are the predefined variable. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on your situations:

[Suggested if your log files are small in size]
You may want to backup your logs by just add a cron job, and zip/tar it to another folder, as a snapshot.  Since the log files are small, even zip/tar everything may need to take you many many years to fill-up your hard drive.

[Suggested if your log files are large]
In your script that generate logs, you may want to rotate through a few indexed files, say, log.0 to log.6, each for one week day, from Sunday to Saturday.   And you can have another script to backup yesterday's log (so that it won't have race conditions between the log producer and the log consumer, i.e. the log mover/copier).  You can have strategies for how many days of backup will be still existing, and for how long of those should be discarded.

The yesterdays' log mover/copier can be easily done by a cron job.